# How I can solve this nonlinear second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a non-linear ODE. Let $g(x)$ is an arbitrary smooth real function, I want to solve the following equation

> $2f(x)f''(x) +4(f'(x))^2=g(x)$

for $f(x)$.
Multiplying $\dfrac32 f(x)$, I obtain $(f^3(x))''=\dfrac32f(x)g(x)$. In the following case I have solved the Eq.

$\bullet$ If $g(x)$ identically be zero, then $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{ax+b}$, for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

$\bullet$ If $g(x)=\alpha f^2(x)$ for some constant $\alpha$, then by taking $f^3(x)=F(x)$, the equation can be solved. In fact, we have $F''(x)=\dfrac32 \alpha F(x)$.

But, in general case of $g(x)$, I do not know how solve the equation.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try writing $f(x)$ and$g(x)$ as power series.

Answer (score 2):

You can only solve it for some particular $g(x)$
$$2f(x)f''(x) +4(f'(x))^2=g(x)$$
It can be solved for $g=-2ff''$
$$4(f'f)'=0$$
$$(f^2)''=0$$
It can also be solved for $g=h(f')$ where $h$ is  any function of $f'$:
$$2f(x)f''(x) +4(f'(x))^2=h(f'(x))$$
$$2f(x)p\dfrac {dp}{df} +4p^2=h(p)$$
The DE is separable.

You integrated the DE for $g=0$ you can maybe  also integrate it for $g= \rm{constant}$ then it becomes separable with $f'=p$. Then you can at least reduce the order of the DE.